# How to get audio to play through headphones or external speakers than computer

Tags: vb.net, audio, wav

I am programming windows form that plays single frequencies at random. I am able to get the audio to play, but the audio is playing through the computer itself. Here is the code that I am using to play the audio:

```
Private soundFileNames() As Integer = {100, 4000, 9050, 15500}



Private Sub playNextFreq_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles playNextFreq.Click
'Random index is chosen using a random number generator
index = CInt(Int(((soundFileNames.Length - 1) * Rnd()) + 0))

'Declares where the audio will be playing from.
Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = soundFileNames(index).ToString() + ".wav"

'Verify the files existence
If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) Then
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(strLocationAndNameOfFile, AudioPlayMode.Background)
Else
    MsgBox(strFileError)
End If

end sub
```

I'm sorry about the bad formatting. But, I hope you can get the general idea.

My.Computer.Audio.Play(..) is the only method that I can find to play audio with a click.

Comment: That's odd.  I thought this method plays through whatever is hooked up.  Do your headphones play the same files out of MediaPlayer?

Comment: I don't think I really understand your question. Are you asking if I play the wav files through media player, does the audio come through the speakers?

Comment: Yes, or the headphones when you plug them in.  The documentation on the .Play appears it goes to the standard sound output.  From my Tech Support days, I'm ruling out if there is something in the sound card settings or something is off hardware wise?